# check if pipe opened before writing

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I would like to know if there is a possible way to check if pipe is opened before writting to it? I don't want the other end of pipe to read from it if it is opened, I just want to check if pipe is going to send SIGPIPE signal and if there is just close my program. The program that has read(...) should not react.

EDIT: Answer was simple.. I is enough to just write a msg 0 byte long...

Comment: Not clear... Precise what exactly is your problem. I feel there is some contradiction: pipe "opened before writing" but the other end has "read if it is opened"?

Comment: I have 4 deamons that send through pipe msg to main process on signal and main process reads from it. Now lets say that the main process randomly closes pipe (its pipe not fifo). I want mine deamons to send a "check msg" to pipe (lets say every 5 sec) to check if its still opened if not sigpipe should kill deamon. The main process shouldn't see check msg

Comment: I never tried it but Opengroup `write` documentation says that if you use the `I_SWROPT` flag with `ioctl` on your descriptor then a zero-sized message can be sent, thus nothing is received but the write would detect your condition.

Comment: will try and if works, I will deliver

Comment: hey I am sorry but I'm a newb when it comes to linux programming, I use ioctl instead of write, or is it setting something for write?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a named pipe?

One thing you can do with those is open the named pipe for reading (and of course writing too) in your writer as well as in your reader. When you run you writer this flags the pipe as open at both ends, though of course your writer will not actually read from it.

See [this manpage on fifos](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo). It looks like multiple processes can open the pipe for reading.